# Access is slow over the network

Tags: ms-access, networking, vba

I'm using a Microsoft Access desktop application, and this is located in a shared folder in the company network.

The access to the network database sometimes is really slow, for example: 
when importing a new csv file with 3000 rows, in some cases, it takes about 27 seconds, but most of the times and other computers it takes more than 30 minutes.

What should i do to solve this situation ?

I've the database splited, applied most of the performance tips regarding databases, and still, just in my computer is where is the fastest, my co-workers computers take more than 30 minutes.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This is difficult to answer, to be honest. How big is the csv? If it's that bad, could you try to cut the csv in half and see if you gain any performance? Are you using VBA for this, or the import wizard? Have you tried Excel over csv?

Comment: How is the CSV file imported? Manually, or with VBA? If with VBA, please share your code. I have spent years working on identifying performance issues and making improvements, but more information is needed. Is your computer 'always 27 seconds' or just most of the time? Are other's 'always 30 minutes'? I assume your co-workers are: in the same building, using identical software, same network, etc.??

Comment: You wrote the database is split, but has every user their own local frontend? Or is it on the network too?

Comment: @All - Equal software, equal network, the csv file has 15 columns and about 3500 rows, more or less.
The import is made in VBA. 
The timings are mostly the same they vary a bit (27 to 35 seconds) and my co-workers (25 minutes to 32)

Comment: I suppose is not because of the code, since this works fine over the network on my computer, but my co-workers computer it takes too long...

Comment: Is the backend on your PC, or on a network share?

Comment: the backend (database) is in the network share folder, and the front end is in each user desktop

Comment: Can you post your code? AT the least, put multiple timer displays in your code to narrow down the part that takes the longest. Can you share that part? Does your code simply do a 'DoCmd.TransferText...' or ???

Comment: Do you have a persistent connection? Before running the csv, try opening any linked table and minimize that table. Now run the import code. I also assume that slow users are on the same network, and not some WAN?